# VB.NET Create a to a form attached Preview window

Tags: vb.net

I want to create a little window which gets visible when I press a button and is attached to the main Form (like shwon below). I want to use this window to show preview of Images (I gonna have a Listbox and depending on which entry is selected, a picture is shown) How can I do this? And how can I be sure that the window will always be attached to the main Form (not depending on resolution). I tried to do it with a second form, but I can't fix it in the correct position.

[image: Example]
regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your preview form class is `frmPreview` and you open it this way:

`Private mPreviewForm As frmPreview
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        mPreviewForm = New frmPreview
        mPreviewForm.Show()
        AttachPreviewForm()
End Sub`

Then you must reposition it every time the main form is changing size or location:

```
Private Sub AttachPreviewForm()
    If mPreviewForm IsNot Nothing Then
        mPreviewForm.AttachForm(Me)
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub Form1_SizeChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.SizeChanged
    AttachPreviewForm()
End Sub
Private Sub Form1_LocationChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.LocationChanged
    AttachPreviewForm()
End Sub
```

And in the `frmPreview`:

```
Public Sub AttachForm(parent As Form)
    Location = New Point(parent.Left + parent.Width, parent.Top)
    Size = New Size(200, parent.Height)
End Sub
```

Comment: This works completly fine, I just did a minor change from "mPreviewForm = New frmPreview" to "mPreviewForm = frmPreview" to avoid that multiple preview windows could generate over each other ( so only one can be active at a time). btw I guess the gap between the two forms is predefined. is there a way to cahnge it so it is actually 0 pixels gap between each other?

Comment: Just change the line `Location = New Point(parent.Left + parent.Width - delta, parent.Top)` and change `delta` to whatever you want...